# AMPscript & Web Services API - Specifying the API user

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

This is a pretty straight forward question -- is it possible to specify the username and password for the API user when using AMPscript with the web services API? Similar to how you would do this if using some other language like Python or Ruby.

This will allow me to retrieve data and trigger emails from any BU in my account regardless of the hierarchy of BUs.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure its not possible, I have been searching for this information in the past, and could find a solution.

I have only managed to call API's where the username are within the URL like: `HttpGET("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Copenhagen,DK&appid=XXXXXXX")`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it just inherits the permissions of a built-in, server-side user in the business unit.  I'm not aware of any way to specify it with the **[AMPScript](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/#alphalist)** or **[SSJS](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/)** API functions.

There are a couple of SSJS functions for the `Account` and `AccountUser` objects, but they're for retrieving and updating those objects, not for initiating the API calls.